# Плагины на автозаполнение в Sublime Text для Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublime-text

Здравствуйте!

Начал изучать `Rails`, и сразу возник вопрос.

Так как пользуюсь Sublime Text, хотелось бы узнать, есть ли плагины на автозаполнение для Ruby и Rails языков.

PS: вопрос, думаю, не новый, и если где-то подобное обсуждалось - буду благодарен за ссылку.

Спасибо.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05x1Jk4rT1A

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MyKoUFr_bsU

Comment: ctags вам поможет

Answer (score 3):

Плагин: [sublime-rails-snippets](https://github.com/tadast/sublime-rails-snippets).

Удобно настраивается, на примере уже готовых автодополнений можно создавать свои.